# hibernate access outer query field in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the below query which works in Mysql Workbench but get an error in hibernate

```
insert into namingsequences(currentseq, namingtype, scope, sequencekey, startrange, endrange, steprange, rangeactive)        
   select (a.currentseq + 5) as currentseq, namingtype, scope, sequencekey,               startrange, endrange, steprange, rangeactive from namingsequences a
    where a.sequencekey = 'test1123' and a.namingtype = 'test' and a.scope = 'test' 
     and a.currentseq >= a.startrange and a.currentseq <= a.endrange and not exists
     (select 1 from namingsequences b where b.sequencekey = 'test1123' and b.namingtype = 'test' 
      and b.currentseq >= b.startrange and b.currentseq <= b.endrange
      and b.scope = 'test' and b.currentseq = (a.currentseq+5) )
      order by currentseq ;

    insert into NamingSequences ( namingtype, scope, sequencekey,startrange,                         
    endrange, steprange, currentseq, rangeactive ) 
    select namingsequ0_.namingtype as col_0_0_, namingsequ0_.scope as col_1_0_,        
    namingsequ0_.sequencekey as col_2_0_, namingsequ0_.startrange as col_3_0_, 
    namingsequ0_.endrange as col_4_0_, namingsequ0_.steprange as col_5_0_, 
    namingsequ0_.currentseq+? as col_6_0_, namingsequ0_.rangeactive as  col_7_0_ from NamingSequences namingsequ0_ 
    where namingsequ0_.sequencekey=? and namingsequ0_.namingtype=? and namingsequ0_.scope=? 
    and namingsequ0_.currentseq>=namingsequ0_.startrange and namingsequ0_.currentseq<=namingsequ0_.endrange 
    and  not (exists (select 1 from NamingSequences namingsequ1_ where 
     namingsequ1_.sequencekey=? and namingsequ1_.namingtype=? 
     and  namingsequ1_.currentseq>=namingsequ1_.startrange 
     and namingsequ1_.currentseq<=namingsequ1_.endrange 
     and namingsequ1_.scope=? and   
     namingsequ1_.currentseq=NamingSequences.currentseq+?)) 
     order by namingsequ0_.currentseq
```

[DEV: 2018-Feb-28 16:32:47,884][WARN ][http-nio-8082-exec-35]SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22

[DEV: 2018-Feb-28 16:32:47,884][ERROR]http-nio-8082-exec-35 Unknown column **'NamingSequences.currentseq'** in 'where clause'

It seems that it cannot access the outer query field from the subquery. The error seems to be from the hibernate query penultimate line.
Also, can i restrict that only one row will be returned by select and inserted?

```java
Query hbquery = session.createQuery(queryString);
hbquery.setMaxResults(1);
hbquery.setParameter("scope", scope);
hbquery.setLong("increment", step);
hbquery.setParameter("nameType", namingType);
hbquery.setParameter("seqKey", seqKey);
int ret = hbquery.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Changing to session.createSQLQuery(queryString) works.